# Why this friend function can't access a private member of the class?

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error when I try to access bins private member of the `GHistogram` class from within the `extractHistogram()` implementation:

```
error: 'QVector<double> MyNamespace::GHistogram::bins' is private
error: within this context
```

Where the 'within this context' error points to the `extractHistogram()` implementation. Does anyone knows what's wrong with my friend function declaration?

Here's the code:

```
namespace MyNamespace{

class GHistogram
{

public:
    GHistogram(qint32 numberOfBins);
    qint32 getNumberOfBins();

    /**
     * Returns the frequency of the value i.
     */
    double getValueAt(qint32 i);
    friend GHistogram * MyNamespace::extractHistogram(GImage *image, 
                                                      qint32 numberOfBins);

private:
    QVector<double> bins;
};

GHistogram * extractHistogram(GImage * image, 
                              qint32 numberOfBins);

} // End of MyNamespace
```

Comment: Is `Gbdi` a class or namespace?  You have `Gbdi::extractHistogram` as the friend.

Comment: Sorry, replace Gbdi by MyNamespace. GBDI is the name of research group where I work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my GCC the above code does not compile because the declaration of `extractHistogram()` appears after the class definition in which it is `friend`ed.  The compiler chokes on the `friend` statement, saying that `extractHistogram` is neither a function nor a data member.  All works well and `bins` is accessible when I move the declaration to before the class definition (and add a forward declaration `class GHistogram;` so that the return type is known to the compiler).  Of course the code for `extractHistogram()` should be written inside the namespace, either by

```
namesapce MyNameSpace {
// write the function here
}
```

or

```
GHistogram *MyNameSpace::extractHistogram( //....
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried to declare extractHistogram() before the class declaration, but it didn't work because it was missing the namespace scope in the function implementation -- I tought that I just had to use the 'using namespace' clause...

Answer (score 2):

Try just:

```
friend GHistogram *extractHistogram(GImage *image, qint32 numberOfBins);
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. The correct is MyNamespace instead of Gbdi int he code. When I remove the MyNamespace I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `Gbdi::extractHistogram` to be a friend to `GHistogram`, but you declare a *function* named `extractHistogram` and expect it to friend with `GHistogram`. `extractHistogram` should be a member of `Gbdi`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. The correct is MyNamespace instead of Gbdi in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant:

```
 friend GHistogram * extractHistogram(GImage *image, qint32 numberOfBins);
```

*This is probably not the reason but a suggestion:*

One more thing, you don't need to declare a function out of a class if it is such class's friend and you already declared it within the class.

In other words:

```
//Your.h
class Foo
{
friend void m();
}
void m(); //This is totally unnecessary

//Your.cpp
void m()
{
}
```

Comment: But if I do that, when I try to invoke m() from, say int main() in 'main.cpp' I will get an error that tells me that 'm() was not declared in this scope' even if I include the 'Your.h' in my 'main.cpp'.

Comment: You're totally right. It slipped my mind because I normally don't do that. I will deleting that. Sorry.